# Join all rows in table with first matched row in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables, and i want `table1 left join table2`, idea is to **show all table1's rows and for each table1's row, i search records in all table2 until the 1st matched value.**

So `results' row number = talbe1's row number`, just add table2's 1st matched value, but here i get `results' row number > talbe1's row number`

Comment: This question was answered many times on SO. Look for questions with greatest-n-per-group and sql-server. Look for solution with `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: why is this tagged with sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your table structures and how you join them. I can think of an example that the row number of the result > table 1 row number.

```
create table staff (
     staff_id int,
     name varchar(100)
)
;
create table stationery (

    s_id int,
    name varchar(100),
    staff_id int
)
;
insert into staff values (1, 'Peter');
insert into staff values (2, 'Sally');

insert into stationery values (1, 'ruler', 1);
insert into stationery values (2, 'pencil', 1);
insert into stationery values (3, 'pencil', 2);

select * 
from staff s1
left join stationery s2 on s1.staff_id = s2.staff_id ;
```

STAFF_ID NAME S_ID

---

1   Peter   1
1  Peter   2
2     Sally   3

Comment: 1 Peter 1 ruler
2 Sally 3 pencil    how to get this please?

Comment: you may try at http://sqlfiddle.com/